# Trigger to update other checkboxes if one is checked

Tags: apex, trigger

Our companies Salesforce is connected to another system, which pushes updates to Salesforce, when the information is updated there.

Is there a way to create a trigger, that updates other checkboxes, if one checkbox called "Overall Responsibility" is checked.
This is for the Contact Object.

This does not work with a workflow rule, as no one is "Saving" the updates.

BR,
Emanuel

Comment: yes, you can create!

Comment: @rahul gawale, I am not very good in writing APEX. 
Could you tell me what the code should look like?

Comment: I really think we need more detail on both the integration model and the data model to provide a fully informed answer here. SFSE's model generally doesn't include writing code on your behalf, but we certainly can assist you in debugging or understanding what the best architectural solution might be.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done on different ways. Depending the type of integration you are using you could already update the checkbox as part of your integration. You can also have Triggers taking care of update and after that executing and making those changes. I think that you should try to create a Batchable operation that can be fire from your trigger.

The point is that you don't know how many records are coming and to be save rather than sorry, Apex Batch will make those changes asynchronously.

To start writing a trigger you can go **[here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro)**.

As I mentioned, for this type of updates will be much efficient to run asynchronously and to use an **[Apex Bacth](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex)** to accomplish this.